# ionic 2 offline pdf view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have developed an ionic 3 app that can retrieve book info from a remote server. The app can read the pdf books embedded in a google docs iframe. Currently it works online.

view-book.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>View book</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" [src]="pdfUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>


</ion-content>
```

view-book.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-view-book',
  templateUrl: 'view-book.html',
})
export class ViewBookPage {
    book: any;
    pdfUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, 
              public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.book = navParams.data.book;
    // get url of pdf and embed in iframe from google docs
    this.pdfUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        'http://docs.google.com/gview?url='+this.book+'&embedded=true');

  }
```

The issue now is that I would like to be able the store the google docs web page somehow or view the remote book without downloading the pdf so that I can read it offline without internet. Please help, thanks.

Comment: That seems more like a design question than a programming question. What you could do for example is download and save the PDF on the device when the device is online and accesses a book. So that later you can load it from the device memory.

Comment: So are you saying that's the only way? Cant I cache the embedded page or something?

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible. To my intuition that's the most straightforward way, but maybe there's some functionality I'm not aware of. I simply told you what approach I'd use.